# Jquery-rotate working if initial element is an image, but not if canvas

Tags: jquery, canvas, rotation

http://chrishorsnell.co.uk/emblem/rotate.php

I am trying to make an image rotate. The jquery rotate plugin ( code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/ # sorry can only do 1 hyperlink ) plugin works fine, I have got it to work on an image (see example 2), but I am trying to implement it into something else and the image is already a canvas (see example 1).

The plugin starts with an image, then turns it into a canvas and uses that from the 2nd rotate onwards. When I try and get it to run on the canvas I have already created previously it wont work.

Also when rotating the 1st example, firebug throws out this

```
uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE) [nsIDOMCanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage]" nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)" location: "JS frame :: http://chrishorsnell.co.uk/emblem/jquery.rotate.1-1.js :: anonymous :: line 57" data: no]
```

This is line 57 of jquery.rotate.1-1.js

```
context.drawImage(canvas.oImage, 0, 0, canvas.oImage.width, canvas.oImage.height);
```

I think the problem lies between line 29-34 of jquery.rotate.1-1.js, but cant figure out how to sort it

```
    if (!p.oImage) {
        canvas.oImage = new Image();
        canvas.oImage.src = p.src;
    } else {
        canvas.oImage = p.oImage;
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at line 2 of jquery.rotate.1-1.js:

```
jQuery.fn.rotate = function(angle,whence,translate_w,translate_h) {
    var p = this.get(0);
```

And if you look in firebug, when you (try to) rotate the image, it send multiple queries to `undefined`.

So? Well, you seem call `rotate()` somehow invalidly, so its inner function has `this == $`.

And it calls `this.get(0)`, which it therefore interprets as `$.get(0)` and performs an XHR to `undefined`.

Let's solve part of it: replace line 2 with:

```
var p = $(this).get(0); // don't do this. Instead:

if ( this === jQuery ) { throw new Exception("Don't pass jQuery object here!"); }
var p = this.get(0);
```

<del>This way, you can't accidentally call `$.get()`: it will fail because of too much recursion.</del>

EDIT: I was being stupid. Check that `this != jQuery`, and throw an error. Much better.

Now for the reason it fails:

The rotate plugin wants an image. If it doesn't have that, it tries to do illegal stuff, and fails. Therefore, give it an image. Or, write the rotate code yourself.

Comment: Well you solved the error, but that wasn't really the reason for this post., just a by product of the rotate not working.
Its only looking for an image initially, after that when its swapped the image with a canvas it works as I would want it to, any idea on how to use the rotate plugin with a canvas from the start?

Comment: Look at the source of the plugin and try to understand it. It uses a canvas but loads the image into it a certain way *then* uses the canvas features to rotate the image. It cannot rotate an entire canvas, which I assume will be more than a simple image. You need to write your own code for that.

Comment: Of course, you could also produce an image from the canvas, then pass it to the plugin... which would require a bit of modification of the plugin code. But that's a bit overkill and in no way efficient.

Comment: guess I will have to work out the creating the image from the canvas route, as you say its not as simple as rotating the entire canvas. thanks for your help, back to the drawing board for me